# Removing Columns containing NaN and corresponding column in other matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have following problem:

- matrix A containing numbers and NaNs
- same size matrix B containing only numbers

I want to:

- delete all columns containing at least one NaN in matrix A
- delete the corresponding column in matrix B

No idea how to do that...
For deleting the columns with NaN I used

```
CompanyDataTimeWindow = estPer3(:,isfinite(sum(estPer3)))
```

However I have no idea how to delete corresponding column in B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
NaNCols = any(isnan(A));
A = A(:,~NaNCols)
B = B(:,~NanCols)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[rows, cols] = find(isnan(A)); 
A(:,unique(cols)) = [];
B(:,unique(cols)) = [];
```